# Drupal 7 programmatically submit form

Tags: drupal-7

```
$form2_id = 'commerce_product_ui_product_form';

$form2_state['values'] = array(
    'sku' => 'xyz100',
    'title' => 'xyz',
    'commerce_price' => '355',
    'op' => t('Save Product')
 );

 drupal_form_submit($form2_id, $form2_state);

$form_errors = form_get_errors();
drupal_set_message('Form errors = '.$form_errors);
```

I get no errors but lots of warnings... and the data is not saved to the db.

call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'commerce_product_product_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently are trying to programmatically submit values to a [Drupal commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) generated form. This an unpractical approach, because of the modular achitecture of Drupal commerce: there are quite a few steps that populate a form before it is submitted, and even if you had (as you should have, anyway) prepoulate `$form_state` with `drupal_get_form()`, you would end up with errors in the submit function. I tried myself to fix your code, to no avail.

Fortunately, there is another approach, leveraging Drupal's entities, for which I must credit [this post](http://dropbucket.org/node/288). You can create an entity metadata wrapper with a Drupal commerce's product object of your chosen type:

> $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product',
>   commerce_product_new('[PRODUCT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME]'));

By calling entity_metadata_wrapper this way, you create a property wrapper by which you can access a `commerce_product` entity; `commerce_product_new('[PRODUCT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME]')` creates the entity instance with it's required defaults. Then you can do:

```
$wrapper->sku = 'xyz100';
$wrapper->title = 'xyz';
$wrapper->commerce_price->amount = 355;
$wrapper->commerce_price->currency_code = 'USD';
```

Be aware that `commerce_price` is a structured type, and `amount` and `currency` are required. `amount` must be in hundredths of the unit, so a 1.5$ price must be expressed as 150.
When your entity is fully populated with any other property, you need to issue

```
$wrapper->save();
```

When I first read your question I thought "this should be easy"... It wasn't and I spent a few hours to figure it out. It was worth the while, though, because I have found a much better solution to deal with entities (and nodes...) in Drupal.

Comment: I too tried using drupal_get_form(), but no luck. This is the elegant solution.